# Undertale pacifist run without Photoshop Flowey

Tags: undertale

I tried to beat Asgore six times and failed each time. So I decided to go back and get some more healing items. But while I was going through my resort I got a call from Undyne telling me to deliver a letter to Alphys. I went through the date with Alphys and as I was heading out of the dump I got a call from Papyrus (Flowey) telling me to go to Alphys lab.

This stuff usually only happens after you've been to the True Lab, but I haven't beaten Asgore or Photoshop Flowey yet. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Has someone else played and completed Undertale on your PC?

Comment: No ive been playing for the last six hours

Comment: Clarification: the True Lab is the section that happens ***after*** you go to Alphy's lab after the date with Alphy. AFAIK, the call from Undyne is supposed to **not** happen on your first run - actual conditions for it happening were unclear last time I checked. I didn't get a call from her despite being 100% Pacifist, having playdates with both Papyrus and Undyne, crossing that bridge several times, and dying to Asgore about 14 times.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you did the TRUE LAB and did the DATING things with Undyne, Alphys, and Papyrus, AND did not kill anyone, youll be able to do pacifist.

Answer (score -4):

There are fake resets in this game.

If you do the game and restart again many things can be diferent, thats because you didin't true reset the game.

After a fake reset the game restart but with internal values randomly generated that can alterate the game itself, thats the cause.

Just true reset the game and try again :)